# Make phrases enumerable?

Tags: enumerable, phrase

I am writing a package which needs to make some customized phrases (e.g. a bunch of city names) externally accessible. (like a normal enum with name 'MyEnum', when user types in "MyEnum.", all its enumerated members will pop up to let user choose)

I tried enum a bunch of city names as follows, but of course it didn't work.

```
public enum City
{
Los Angeles,
Santa Francisco,
Houston,
New York
}
```

I also read some earlier articles about using string attributes on enum fields, but these strings can not pop up for external use.

Any helps? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its cause an error because a white space.

Try this

```
public enum City
{
    LosAngeles,
    SantaFrancisco,
    Houston,
    NewYork
}
```

[Here is a sample of how to use enum.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum)